# Creating file to specific directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm creating a program to take YouTube videos and convert them into mp3's and store them in a specific folder.

Every time my program is ran, it will make sure the file directory exists as well as the folder and text file inside of it, if not, it will create these. However when running my program, it does in fact create a file in the specified directory, but it will not create the json file (which is where I will store the file path directory so the user doesn't have to input the directory every time).

The program doesn't close, it doesn't throw an error, it just simply does nothing after creating the file. It shows a blinking cursor and just idles. I'm a newbie here so I'm probably missing something very simple but. I can't figure it out, the code I'm supplying below isn't the whole program, just the function that keeps messing up:

```
def _check_dir_path() -> bool:
    if os.path.exists(file_dir):
        while True:
            song_path = os.path.join(file_dir, "sp_songs")
            dir_file = os.path.join(file_dir, "Song File Directory.json")
            if os.path.isdir(song_path):
                if os.path.isfile(dir_file):
                    return True
                else:
                    sp_songs = open("sp_songs", "w")
                    json.dump(path_dir, sp_songs)
                    sp_songs.close()
                    continue
            else:
                os.mkdir(song_path)
                continue
```

Comment: The program never closes because `while True` is an infinite loop

Comment: @vojtam Yes, however the program should create the files and run the loop again, at which point it'll return True and move on, the folder gets created but the file does not

Answer (score 0):

I realized I wasn't specifying a directory, I was creating a file in my python project folder but checking for that file in the specified directory which meant it'll never return true:

```
sp_songs = open("sp_songs", "w")
```

By replacing 'sp_songs' with 'dir_file' I was specifying the path:

```
sp_songs = open(dir_file, "w")
```